# Python prime fibonacci

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

Prime Fibonnaci
Problem Description
Given two numbers n1 and n2

1. Find prime numbers between n1 and n2, then
2. Make all possible unique combinations of numbers from the prime numbers list you found in step 1.
3. From this new list, again find all prime numbers.
4. Find smallest (a) and largest (b) number from the 2nd generated list, also count of this list.
5. Consider smallest and largest number as the 1st and 2nd number to generate Fibonacci series respectively till the count (number of primes in the 2nd list).
6. Print the last number of a Fibonacci series as an output

Constraints
2 <= n1, n2 <= 100

n2 - n1 >= 35

Input Format
One line containing two space separated integers n1 and n2.

Output
Last number of a generated Fibonacci series.

Timeout
1

Test Case
Example 1

Input

2 40

Output

13158006689

Explanation

1st prime list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]

Combination of all the primes = [23, 25, 27, 211, 213, 217, 219, 223, 229, 231, 32, 35, 37, 311, 313, 319, 323, 329, 331, 337, 52, 53, 57, 511, 513, 517, 519, 523, 529, 531, 537, 72, 73, 75, 711, 713, 717, 719, 723, 729, 731, 737, 112, 113, 115, 117, 1113, 1117, 1119, 1123, 1129, 1131, 1137, 132, 133, 135, 137, 1311, 1317, 1319, 1323, 1329, 1331, 1337, 172, 173, 175, 177, 1711, 1713, 1719, 1723, 1729, 1731, 1737, 192, 193, 195, 197, 1911, 1913, 1917, 1923, 1929, 1931, 1937, 232, 233, 235, 237, 2311, 2313, 2317, 2319, 2329, 2331, 2337, 292, 293, 295, 297, 2911, 2913, 2917, 2919, 2923, 2931, 2937, 312, 315, 317, 3111, 3113, 3117, 3119, 3123, 3129, 3137, 372, 373, 375, 377, 3711, 3713, 3717, 3719, 3723, 3729, 3731]

2nd prime list=[193, 3137, 197, 2311, 3719, 73, 137, 331, 523, 1931, 719, 337, 211, 23, 1117, 223, 1123, 229, 37, 293, 2917, 1319, 1129, 233, 173, 3119, 113, 53, 373, 311, 313, 1913, 1723, 317]

smallest (a) = 23

largest (b) = 3719

Therefore, the last number of a Fibonacci series i.e. 34th Fibonacci number in the series that has 23 and 3719 as the first 2 numbers is 13158006689

Example 2

Input

30 70

Output

2027041

Explanation

1st prime list=[31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67]

2nd prime list generated form combination of 1st prime list = [3137, 5953, 5347, 6761, 3761, 4337, 6737, 6131, 3767, 4759, 4153, 3167, 4159, 6143]

smallest prime in 2nd list=3137
largest prime in 2nd list=6761

Therefore, the last number of a Fibonacci series i.e. 14th Fibonacci number in the series that has 3137 and 6761 as the first 2 numbers is 2027041

```
from itertools import permutations
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    else:
        return True
def listPrime(n1,n2):
    lis=[]
    for ele in range(n1,n2+1):
        if isPrime(ele)==True:
            lis.append(ele)
    return lis

def returnPrime(lis):
    r=[]
    for ele in lis:
        if isPrime(ele)==True:
            r.append(ele)
    return r

def fibo(mi,ma,c):
    f=mi
    s=ma
    res=[]
    res.append(f)
    res.append(s)
    for i in range(2,c):
        next=f+s  
        res.append(next)
        f,s=s,next
    return res[-1]

def main(n1,n2):
    primeNo=listPrime(n1,n2)
    comb=permutations(primeNo,2)
    r=[]
    for ele in comb:
        r.append(int(str(ele[0])+str(ele[1])))
    comb2=returnPrime(r)
    count=len(comb2)
    mini=min(comb2)
    maxi=max(com2)
    res=fibo(mini,maxi,count)
    return res


if __name__=="__main__":
    lis=list(map(int,input().split()))
    lis[0]=n1
    lis[1]=n2
    res=main(n1,n2)
    print(res)
```

Please help me write the right solution to the code
Also help me optimize it so it runs in below 1 seconds

Comment: Did you run the code on the example you gave? Check the code is computing the correct (given) intermediate result at each step 1, 2, 3, ... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Profile in which method most time is spent**. A wild guess would be `isPrime(..)`. So try to optimize that.

1. Speedup of 2 by checking even separately and than only check in the loop only odd numbers.

1b. You can improve this even more by storing a list of the first m primes and
check them up front.

2. you could keep found primes up to a certain value and every number smaller than the highest of your primes that is not in the set of your primes is no prime.

There are a lot of clever ways to implement `isPrime(...)` just google it and you will find a vast amount of optimization ideas for it.

Comment: You're guessing what's wrong with the code (that the main problem is that it's slow) and guessing that it's because `isPrime` is the culprit. Better to actually know what's wrong with the code when you post an answer (which one can get from debugging).

Comment: Ok satisfied with answer on optimized part! But can you explain with writting a code on this problem which would be time efficient modular and clean.

Comment: (As you did edit this: make it *time is spen**t***.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_prime(x):
   if x&1 == 0: return 0
   for i in range(3,int(x**0.5)+1,2):
     if x%i==0: return 0
   return 1

n1,n2 = 30,70
min = 9789
max = 23
count = 0
freq = {}
if n1&1 == 0:
   l = [i for i in range(n1+1,n2+1,2) if check_prime(i)]
else:
   l = [i for i in range(n1,n2+1,2) if check_prime(i)]
if n1 == 2: l = [2] + l
for x in l:
   for y in l:
      if x != y:
         n = int(str(x)+str(y))
         if n not in freq:
            if check_prime(n):
                freq[n] = 1
                if n<min: min = n
                elif n>max: max = n
                count += 1
while count>1:
   min,max = max,min+max
   count -= 1

print(min)
```

Comment: An explanation to go along with your code would be helpful.